# Find coordinate vector in matrix vector space

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

How do I do this question?
I don't understand the notation that describes B
what is the superscript ij? what is E?

[image]

Comment: I think you should provide more detailed information about your problem.

Comment: sorry, the link did not work; will reupload

Comment: Understand $E^{i,j}$ (which could have been written $E_{i,j}$ as well) as the $2 \times 3$ matrix having 0 entries but the entry on line $i$ and column $j$ which is 1. Thus in your problem, $v=1E^{11}+2E^{12}+\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any objects of a particular kind that can be added together and multiplied by numbers to produce another object of the same kind are called vectors. From this point of view, matrices of a given dimension (including $2\times3$) qualify as vectors. The space of $2\times3$ is six dimensional and so any basis is must contain $6$ elements.

In this problem, you were given a basis with $6$ elements, albeit in terrible notation. The letter $E$ does often refer to some kind of unit object, but without a better description, one can only guess what they mean. We're guessing

$$
\mathcal{B}=\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
 \right\}
$$
in which case $$\mathbf{v}_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\1\\-1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}.$$

If you are interested in learning more about this perspective on linear algebra, check out the linear algebra course on Lemma http://lem.ma